# Git: Keep certain files in Current Working Directory and only in the latest commit

Tags: git, pdf, github, synchronization, gitignore

I use *.gitignore* to ignore pdf files as the *.git* folder becomes quite huge after some time. I also use github as a cloud storage as I have to access my repository from different systems.

There is always some reference *pdf* files that I would like to be stored in my working directory as well as only in the latest commit so that when I sync to the other system, the *pdf* files become available. At the same time, in the interest of keeping lightweight *.git*  folder, I would like the *pdf* files to be removed from previous commits when I make a new commit.

Is there a nifty trick to do it automatically.

Please comment so that I could improve this question. Thanks.

**UPDATE**

*pdf* files can change from time to time, as some comments get added to the file, or some text gets highlighted (or underlined). The *pdf* file can remain at the tip of the recently updated branch. Basically, I wanted to access some files from every system without it being tracked.

Comment: Please comment so that I could improve this question. Thanks.

Comment: I really don't understand the reason for the downvotes. Please let me know if this question is not useful or wrongly placed.

Comment: Indeed some comments with the downvotes would have been nice. I assume they came into being because your request does not make much sense: If the PDF does not change, it should be only once in your repository, no matter in how many commits it is still present. Furthermore, what about branches? Should the PDF remain in every branch head? Or only in the most recently updated branch? Additionally, removing files from commits changes their structure and their hash. In case of branches from that commit a change would cause quite a lot of changes leaving quite a lot of garbage in your repository..

Comment: @mkl Thanks, I have added the update at the bottom of my question. Basically, I wanted to access some files from every system, without tracking changes to it.

Comment: You seem to be thinking of Git as if it were a Dropbox clone. That's not what it is. While it may be _possible_ to do what you want via history rewriting (e.g. via `git filter-branch`) you'll be fighting against the tool the whole way. I suggest you find another tool that may be a better fit. In this case, simply using Dropbox or similar may work (I don't know what else is in your working directory).

Comment: I am not sure but git-lfs (https://git-lfs.github.com/) might help me. If anybody has any experience with this, can you comment, please?

Comment: @Chris You are right I had Dropbox in my mind while writing this question. I just wanted to have related projects file in the same folder which is initialized to git. And I didn't wanted to store entire Repo in dropbox as it will, be duplication.